# Mute MPMoviePlayerController in ios or Play video using AVPlayer in ios with mute option

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can i mute the video in MPMoviePlayerController in IOS. I am very frustrated by searching the code. Please help me to way out. I am stuck over this for the past 20 days. Or Please guide to Play using AVPlayer with mute option.

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer has "muted" boolean field, just set it to "YES".